# Imported two separate text files to organize into dict, does not reading 2nd file properly and get a KeyError for any data in the 2nd file

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to add all branded and generic cereals under one dictionary and separate it with a key named `main_brand` holding a Boolean value.

This is in the file `mainbrands.txt`

```
# Brand Name,Company,Founded

Apple Jacks,Kellogg's,1965
Cheerios,General Mills,1941
...
```

This is in the file `genericbrands.txt`

```
Apple Jills,AFirm,2011
Cheery Oats,BFirm,2015
...
```

This is under my `main.py`

```
import os
branded = open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'mainbrands.txt'), 'r').readlines()
generic= open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'genericbrands.txt'), 'r').readlines()

history = {'founded': {}, 'main_brand': {}}

for x in range(0, len(branded)):
    data = branded[x].strip().split(',')
    history[data[0]] = {'company': data[1], 'founded': data[2], 'main_brand': True}

for y in range(0, len(generic)):
    data = generic[y].strip().split(',')
    history[data[0]] = {'company': data[1], 'founded': data[2], 'main_brand': False}

def history_check(key):
    key_list = list(history.keys())
    for i in range(0, len(key_list)):
        if key_list[i] in key:
            return history[key_list[i]]
```

I would like to keep my main brands and generic brands as two separate lists rather than combine the two lists and add on an additional comma deliminator as it will become less readable (this is a simplified toy example)

Some sample outputs are:

```
>>print(history_check('Cherrios')['company'])
General Mills

>>print(history_check('Apple Jacks')['founded'])
1965

>>print(history_check('Cheery Oats')['founded'])
KeyError: 'Cheery Oats'
```

Why are any of my keys from the `genericbrands.txt` not being read?

Comment: you seem to create empty entries in `history = {'company': {}, 'founded': {} ...}` but never put anything in them. I would just define history: `history = {}`. I also don't understand the history_check function that accepts a string then eventually indexes history with that same key. If you want to test existence of the key to avoid missing keys, use `if key in dictionary:` statements

Comment: In this example it actually does look very redundant. In my original program I'm given random strings of random lengths and I'm trying to find a 'key' within the randomly generated strings. This is more of a self-learning project and this was how I went about with trying to solve it. May not be the best why but at least I'm learning more about using dicts.

I was assuming `history = {'company': {}, 'founded': {}, 'main_brand': {}}` initializes the dictionary, I'm I understanding that incorrectly from the documentation?

Comment: I think you're thinking a little bit like a struct in C, but when you assign `history[data[0]] = {'company': data[1], ... }`, you are assigning the value of each history entry to an entire dictionary that contains it's own set of keys and values. with what you have, your history dictionary will look like this: `{'founded': {}, 'main_brand': {}, 'Apple Jacks': {'company': 'Kellog's', 'founded': 1965, 'main_brand': True}, 'Cheerios': {...}, 'Apple Jills: {...} ...}`

Comment: basically you don't need to (and can't) preallocate the keys for the subdictionaries, because they don't exist yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keys from your genericbrands.txt are getting put into the history dictionary.  Take a look for yourself...

```
print(history)
```

Also notice you have dead keys in there like `'company': {}`.  I believe @Aaron is correct just go with it like this `history = {}`

I think this is what you are looking for the history_check to do...

```
def history_check(key):
    return history[key]

print(history_check('Apple Jacks')['founded'])
print(history_check('Cheery Oats')['company'])
```

EDIT:  If you're getting a key error double check your example.  I just copied it exactly and made the changes above to get the output of 1965 and BFirm